# Appenging serve HTML without trailing / in folder

Tags: google-app-engine

I cant seem to find this anywhere.

What I have is an appengine project that just serves html pages. But it only correctly loads   files when the filename is 'exactly' correct.

I.e. **mywebsite.com/lastproject/ loads perfectly**

but **mywebsite.com/lastproject does not load at all**

I want the website to load correctly when the trailing / is left out. What am I missing???

Here is my app.yaml

```
application: websitewithsubfolder
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: (.*)/
  static_files: static\1/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shay means the line should be:

```
- url: (.*)
```

That is a route that handles all URL requests you will not get any 404 errors, and all Requests are handled by a *static* index.html page.  Your second route will not ever be handled as it is more specific and after your generic route.

You want the more specific routes above your catch all routes.

```
application: websitewithsubfolder
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /static/css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /static/js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: (.*)
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

The app.yaml file above is more in line with what you want.

I suggest you read the [app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig) docs which go over this in more detail.

Comment: This seems to work ok for loading the source html, but all the assets are shot. I get the following error many times.    : ERROR    2012-06-03 15:56:50,916 dev_appserver.py:1983] Error encountered reading file "/website/static/style/style.css/index.html":
[Errno 20] Not a directory: 'website/static/style/style.css/index.html'

Comment: @norskben I updated the answer with some other examples that I use in my applications.  

You really need to read the [Google App Engine Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/)

The above app.yaml if you modify it to your application will work, but you have a static html page answering all routes. For you to get real benefit from app engine you need to create an *application*.

Answer (score 0):

Your first mapping in the yaml file tells the AppEngine "every url that ends with / should be mapped to ...". You don't have any mapping to something that doesn't ends with /.

this will map everything to a folder named static/html (untested let me know if it works)

```
- url: /.*
  static_dir: static/html
  mime_type: text/html
```

Comment: if possible, can you give an example. I am really not familiar with this syntax. Thanks!